# Format predefine date into MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, date

I am getting date like "Tue Jan 19 18:25:08 +0000 2010".
I have to convert above date to **MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss or MM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss** format.

I tried and same created a Plunker for the reference. Below is link for the same

Date is formatting correctly but time is not formatting.

https://embed.plnkr.co/2YouE4gQLAuPCOOnvAJF/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) for date related stuff.

In the controller(create a moment object):

```
$scope.date = moment(<date>, 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss Z YYYY'); //format for Tue Jan 19 18:25:08 +0000 2010
```

In the view(manipulate the moment object using angular moment):

```
<p data-ng-bind="date | amDateFormat : 'MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss'"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) for dates.

```
$scope.newDate = moment(yourCurrentDate).format('MM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

You can use this to convert into timestamp in milliseconds:

```
$scope.newDate = moment(yourCurrentDate).format('x');
```

If you want to display a timestamp in milliseconds in any format:

```
<span>{{newDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

Comment: can this not possible without moment? because date is coming in json and i am pushing that date in UI.